# How to return next status following a specific status that has occured

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to return the next status after an order has been received, however only looking to capture certain statuses within the following list: 'Shipped', 'Partially shipped', 'Cancelled'
Below is the orders table

| Order ID | Order Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Received | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | Partially Shipped | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | Returned | 1/2/2021 |
| 1 | Received | 1/2/2021 |
| 1 | Shipped | 1/3/2021 |
| 2 | Received | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | Acknowledged | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | Shipped | 1/1/2021 |

As you can see for order ID 2 the following status after received is Acknowledged, but I want to only grab the next status that falls within the following list : 'Shipped', 'Partially shipped', 'Cancelled'
Therefore the following output would be correct, skipping acknowledged and returning shipped

| Order ID | Order Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Partially Shipped | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | Shipped | 1/3/2021 |
| 2 | Shipped | 1/1/2021 |

Comment: Please don't post pictures of tables.  Just show it as text.  You will want to look at the oracle windowing/analytic functions.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `match_recognize` for this that looks suitable here, because it can handle repetition of the statuses to be included between. It is available for all supported versions (since 12c).

I've added extra rows to show how it handles, for example, `'Shipped'` after `'Partially Shipped'`, and absence of the next status from the list of required statuses (as for `order_id = 3`).

> ```
> with a (Order_ID, Order_Status, dt) as (
>   select 1, 'Received', date '2021-01-01'           from dual union all
>   select 1, 'Partially Shipped', date '2021-01-01'  from dual union all
>   select 1, 'Shipped', date '2021-01-02'           from dual union all
>   select 1, 'Returned', date '2021-02-01'           from dual union all
>   select 1, 'Received', date '2021-02-01'           from dual union all
>   select 1, 'Shipped', date '2021-03-01'           from dual union all
>   select 2, 'Received', date '2021-01-01'           from dual union all
>   select 2, 'Acknowledged', date '2021-01-01'       from dual union all
>   select 2, 'Shipped', date '2021-01-01'           from dual union all
>   select 3, 'Received', date '2021-01-01'           from dual union all
>   select 3, 'Acknowledged', date '2021-02-01'       from dual union all
>   select 3, 'Received', date '2021-03-01'           from dual union all
>   select 4, 'Received', date '2021-01-01'           from dual union all
>   select 4, 'Acknowledged', date '2021-02-01'       from dual union all
>   select 4, 'Received', date '2021-03-01'           from dual union all
>   select 4, 'Acknowledged', date '2021-03-02'       from dual union all
>   select 4, 'Shipped', date '2021-03-05'       from dual
> )
> select *
> from a
> match_recognize (
>   partition by order_id
>   order by dt asc
>   all rows per match
>   /*Return the next status after 'Received', that is in a list of interest*/
>   pattern (
>     {- received -} /*Exclude 'Received' from output*/
>     {- exclude* -} /*Exclude "other" statuses after 'Received'*/
>     next? /*And include the next status that should be in the list.
>             Marked as optional to allow previous exclusion group
>             to catch not listed statuses*/
>   )
>   define
>     received as order_status = 'Received',
>     /*Other statuses (that are out of interest)*/
>     exclude as order_status not in ('Shipped', 'Partially Shipped', 'Cancelled'),
>     /*To break match if the next status is not from the list*/
>     next as order_status in ('Shipped', 'Partially Shipped', 'Cancelled')
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ORDER_ID | DT         | ORDER_STATUS
> -------: | :--------- | :-----------
>        1 | 2021-01-02 | Shipped     
>        1 | 2021-03-01 | Shipped     
>        2 | 2021-01-01 | Shipped     
>        4 | 2021-03-05 | Shipped
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b05d50e9b7c733ad30ce9675a13b7fe7)*

Comment: Do you need to define `next AS order_status not in ('Shipped', 'Partially Shipped', 'Cancelled')` otherwise you may find the "next" status is returned as "Received"?

Comment: I should not have included the "not" in my previous comment; that was a copy-paste error on my part. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you! I've added this test case with `Received` after exclusion list also. I think `next` should be simply a list of required statuses, because we need them and not `'Received'` (and it is more verbose). Also reorganized `exclude` pattern because if `'Received'` will be catched, then no statuses from the list were met up to now, so match should span more rows until it hit `next` pattern. I've deleted my previous misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional `LAG` analytic statement with the `IGNORE NULLS` clause:

```sql
SELECT Order_id,
       Order_status,
       "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAG(
           CASE
           WHEN order_status IN ('Received', 'Shipped', 'Partially Shipped', 'Cancelled')
           THEN order_status
           END
         ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY "DATE") AS prev_status
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  prev_status = 'Received'
AND    order_status IN ('Shipped', 'Partially Shipped', 'Cancelled')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Order_ID, Order_Status, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, 'Received',          DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Partially Shipped', DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Shipped',           DATE '2021-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Returned',          DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Received',          DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Shipped',           DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Received',          DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Acknowledged',      DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Shipped',           DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Received',          DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Acknowledged',      DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Received',          DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Acknowledged',      DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Received',          DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ORDER_ID | ORDER_STATUS | DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Partially Shipped | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | Shipped | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | Shipped | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a17e32df1f712b74fb832aea5c012409)*